# Two-way binding not working for custom input element

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0

I am trying to create a re-usable input element called InputBox and essentially by default the component will use two-way binding for the value.

InputBox.razor

```html
<div class="InputBox">
    <input title="@PlaceHolder" placeholder="@PlaceHolder" type="text" @bind=Value/>
</div>
```

InputBox.razor.cs

```cs
public partial class InputBox
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public string PlaceHolder { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The issue is that whenever I use this component and try to get the current value when a user clicks save, the value the user types is not updating up to the parent.

An example would be:

```cs
<InputBox Value=@username />

<button onclick="@SaveUserName"></button>

@code {
    public string username { get; set; } = "test user";

    public void SaveUserName() 
    {
        log(username); //username outputs 'test user' instead of whatever the user has typed.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently only setting the value with a one-way binding.

```
<InputBox Value=@username />
```

In this snippet here, you are passing the value of `username` into the parameter `Value`, but you don't have any way of updating the `username` property as part of a two-way binding.

For two-way binding you need to set up an event callback.

`InputBox.razor.cs`

```
public partial class InputBox
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public string PlaceHolder { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    // Add this event callback as a public parameter
    // When manually invoking it the name is arbitrary
    // You can set up the property to work with @bind by 
    // using a naming convention, but I can leave that for 
    // you to look into
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnValueChange { get; set; }
}
```

You can then invoke it after your raw input value has changed. This will let any subscribers know that the value has been updated.

**Note** You have tagged this question with .NET 6. .NET 7 and 8 have newer ways of managing the binding pipeline, so I will show you a method that is compatible with .NET 6.

`InputBox.razor`

```
<div class="InputBox">
    <input 
        title="@PlaceHolder" 
        placeholder="@PlaceHolder" 
        type="text" 
        value="@Value"
        @onchange="e => OnValueChange.InvokeAsync(e.Value.ToString())"
     />
</div>
```

Note that I have replaced your `@bind` with `value=...` and `@onchange=...`.

The `value=...` is a one-way binding to set the value of the input from your property. The `@onchange` binds to the change event and creates a two-way binding. In this case the event handler is invoking your event callback, which ultimately passes the updated value back to the parent.

The `e` parameter in the event handler is of type `ChangeEventArgs`. You can use this exact function with `@oninput` too for instant notifications.

### Edit

#### .NET 7+

In .NET 7 and later you have newer syntax to choose from.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

> In ASP.NET Core 7.0 or later, @bind:get/@bind:set modifier syntax is
> used to implement two-way data binding, as the next example
> demonstrates.

This example comes straight from that page:

```
<p>
    <input @bind:event="oninput" @bind:get="inputValue" @bind:set="OnInput" />
</p>

<p>
    <code>inputValue</code>: @inputValue
</p>

@code {
    private string? inputValue;

    private void OnInput(string value)
    {
        var newValue = value ?? string.Empty;

        inputValue = newValue.Length > 4 ? "Long!" : newValue;
    }
}
```

Note here how you can split `@bind=` into a getter (for setting the value, confusingly - think of it from the point of view of the `<input />`), and a setter (to trigger after effects).

You can also choose which event you want to hook into by using `@bind:event`.

#### .NET 8

From .NET 8 you can use `@bind:after=...` along with `@bind=...` so that you can trigger an async callback while still using simple two-way binding syntax.

This example also comes straight from the page linked above.

```
<ChildBind @bind-Year="year" @bind-Year:after="YearUpdated" />

@code {
    ...

    private async Task YearUpdated()
    {
        ... = await ...;
    }
}
```

So you can continue to use `@bind=...` to perform two-way binding, and also use `@bind:after=...` to trigger an event callback that bubbles the change up the call stack.

Comment: so using the native way of two-way binding (@bind=Value) is only possible at the InputBox level? Meaning the parent value is not effected when passed through?

Comment: Correct - @bind=Value only works locally. You have no two-way binding on your parent, so the property never gets updated. Beware: @bind=Value only works locally. It doesn't propagate changes up the call stack.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me again! Is this just a limitation due to the version of .Net I am on or is it still like this is .net 8?

Comment: No problem! The only limitation of being on .NET 6 are the binding options you have. You get a little bit more control in more recent versions - but they're really just syntactic sugar for the example I've presented here. The newer way would be to use a combination of `@bind:get`, `@bind:set`, `@bind:after`. But what you have now works just fine.

Comment: @KurtHamilton thanks, could you please include an extra part in your answer showing how it is done on .NET 8 for this same example?

Comment: @Cfun Done. Who knows what you'll be able to do in .NET 9!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis No prob!

Comment: I have tried the examples from the linked Microsoft article, but two-way binding will not work! I have tried the other approaches also, none will work. I created the Blazor app from Rider EAP, could it be that initial setup in `Program.cs` is incorrect?

Comment: @ThomasEyde it won't be a problem with your `Program.cs` setup. There are quite a few variables to consider. It would be helpful if you could somehow create a minimum reproducible example. For example, this is a working demo of simple 2-way binding. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckwIanmRIYvHeCSG

Comment: Thank you, @KurtHamilton, I have since learned that .NET 8 introduced the concept of interaction. I had to add `@rendermode InteractiveServer` several places.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 8 you have to add `@rendermode` to your components.