# Blazor .NET 8 two-way binding with component in InteractiveServer rendering

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-8.0

What would be the correct way or even if it is possible to set two way binding with component that is using InteractiveServer rendering mode in .NET 8.

`MainLayout.razor` - I would like to receive bool value from the child component:

```
<SwitchComponent @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" @bind-Value1="@ThisValue" />

@ThisValue

@code {
    public bool ThisValue { get; set; }
}
```

And then the component would look like something like this:

```
<button @onclick="@UpdateHeading">Update </button>
@Value1 

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool Value1 { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> Value1Changed { get; set; }

    private Task OnValue1Changed(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void UpdateHeading()
    {
        Value1 = !Value1;
        Value1Changed.InvokeAsync(Value1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();       
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that I can't figure out how to bind the parent property `ThisValue`  to component when child value `Value1` change so should parent value!

Comment: Everything is possible, but your example provides no information as to what `MainLayout` does with `ThisValue` which is rather important in providing a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@bind-get` and `@bind-set`

```
<SwitchComponent @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" @bind-Value1:get="ThisValue"
                 @bind-Value1:set="OnChange" />
@ThisValue
@code{
    public bool ThisValue { get;set;}
}

private void OnChange(bool value)
{
   ThisValue = value;
   //Update "ThisValue" here depending on your logic
}
```

Related question:

[Two-way binding not working for custom input element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77648615/5228202)

Official Docs:

[ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bind-across-more-than-two-components)
.

Comment: [@Cfun] - the OP's component may need some refactoring, but I think his main problem is in making `MainLayout`  an `InteractiveServer` component so the binding works.  [But I may be wrong!]

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis ah i see ! just noticed "MainLayout.razor" i thought it was a regular page where he is consuming his component , let us seek a clarification from the OP

Comment: @Didzis Stivriņš any update ?